# Subsetting data frame by vector of elements

Tags: r, subset

I spent about 20 minutes looking through previous questions, but could not find what I am looking for. I have a large data frame I want to subset down based on a list of names, but the names in the data frame can also have a postfix not indicated in the list.

In other words, is there a simpler generic way (for infinite numbers of postfixes) to do the following:

```
data <- data.frame("name"=c("name1","name1_post1","name2","name2_post1",
                            "name2_post2","name3","name4"),
                   "data"=rnorm(7,0,1),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

names <- c("name2","name3")

subset <- data[ data$name %in% names | data$name %in% paste0(names,"_post1") | data$name %in% paste0(names,"_post2") , ]
```

In response to @Arun's answer. The names in my data actually include more than one underscore, making the problem more complicated.

```
data <- data.frame("name"=c("name1_target_time","name1_target_time_post1","name2_target_time","name2_target_time_post1",
                            "name2_target_time_post2","name3_target_time","name4_target_time"),
                   "data"=rnorm(7,0,1),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

names <- c("name2_target_time","name3_target_time")

subset <- data[ data$name %in% names | data$name %in% paste0(names,"_post1") | data$name %in% paste0(names,"_post2") , ]
```

Comment: 20 minutes? Is it too much for you ?

Comment: Not at all. I am just saying I spent time looking through previous questions before posting.

Comment: You don't spent enough time . And you looks for a very specific solution (using grep), Is in't too much?

Comment: @agstudy sorry if I offended you. I am just trying to learn.

Comment: I am not offended. I just try to tell you that spending 20 minutes to find a solution is not the right way to learn.

Comment: @agstudy I am not saying I haven't spent a lot of time on my own coding. I was merely saying that I looked, as an apology in advance if I missed another post that would have answered my question. I don't understand why that merited a down-vote.

Comment: @dayne, you're fine.   Nice question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** solution using regular expressions (following OP's follow-up in comment):

```
data[grepl(paste(names, collapse="|"), data$name), ]
#          name       data
# 3       name2  1.4934931
# 4 name2_post1 -1.6070809
# 5 name2_post2 -0.4157518
# 6       name3  0.4220084
```

On your new data:

```
#                      name      data
# 3       name2_target_time 0.6295361
# 4 name2_target_time_post1 0.8951720
# 5 name2_target_time_post2 0.6602126
# 6       name3_target_time 2.2734835
```

Also, as @flodel shows under comments, this also works fine!

```
subset(data, sub("_post\\d+$", "", name) %in% names)
```

---

**Old solution:**

```
data[sapply(strsplit(data$name, "_"), "[[", 1) %in% names, ]

#          name       data
# 3       name2  1.4934931
# 4 name2_post1 -1.6070809
# 5 name2_post2 -0.4157518
# 6       name3  0.4220084
```

The idea: First `split` the string at `_` using `strsplit`. This results in a list. For ex: `name2` will result in just `name2` (first element of the list). But `name2_post1` will result in `name2` and `post1` (second element of the list). By wrapping it with `sapply` and using `[[` with `1`, we can select just the "first" element of this resulting list. Then we can use that with `%in%` to check if they are present in `names` (which is straightforward).

Comment: That's really close (upvote). The problem is the real names I am working with have multiple underscores before the postfix. For example "name1_target1_time_1_postfix". I am really looking for some kind of grep function that will check one list for partial matches of another list.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it, I really asked the question to learn more about coding in r. It seems strange to me that there isn't a grep function that will look for multiple patterns.

Comment: It'd be nice if you can edit your post accordingly then showing the input and output?

Comment: Who says there isn't? This is just one of the possible ways. I just dint think *this particular question* requires a `grep`.

Comment: Can you show a grep-like solution? Or show how to grab the first n elements when using sapply? I would be happy to add more complicated names to my example to better reflect my actual data if you would like.

Comment: Like that? `subset(data, sub("_post\\d+$", "", name) %in% names)`

Comment: @Arun Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Arun +1 because you are patient!

Answer (score 0):

A grep solution would probably look something like the following:

```
subset <- data[grep("(name2)|(name3)",names(data)),]
```